# Why do I get “Reducer [...] returned undefined during initialization” despite providing initialState to createStore()?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I had set InitialState in my redux createStore method ,and I corresponding InitialState as second arguments

I got a error in browser:

```
<code>Uncaught Error: Reducer "postsBySubreddit" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined.</code>
```

code is here:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import rootReducer from '../reducers/reducers'
import Immutable from 'immutable'
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger()
//const initialState=0
function configureStore() {
    return createStore(
    rootReducer,
     {postsBySubreddit:{},selectedSubreddit:'reactjs'},
     applyMiddleware(
     thunkMiddleware,
    loggerMiddleware
  )
 )
}
  export default configureStore
```

and I invoked `configeStore`method in `Root.js`:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
 import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
 import configureStore from '../store/configureStore'
 import AsyncApp from './AsyncApp'
 import Immutable from 'immutable'
 const store = configureStore()
 console.log(store.getState())
 export default class Root extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <Provider store={store}>
       <AsyncApp />
     </Provider>
  )
 }
}
```

but I guess this `initateState` has something wrong:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import {reducerCreator} from '../utils/creator'
import Immutable from'immutable'
import {SELECT_SUBREDDIT, INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT ,REQUEST_POSTS, RECEIVE_POSTS} from '../actions/action'
let initialState=Immutable.fromJS({isFetching: false, didInvalidate: false,items:[]})

function selectedSubreddit(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case SELECT_SUBREDDIT:
    return action.subreddit
  default:
    return state
  }
}
function postsBySubreddit(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
function posts(state=initialState,action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
      return state.merge({
        didInvalidate: true
      })
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
      return state.merge({
        isFetching: true,
        didInvalidate: false
      })
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
      return state.merge({
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        items: action.posts,
        lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
      })
    default:
      return state 
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  postsBySubreddit,
 selectedSubreddit
})
export default rootReducer
```

but if I set `initialState` in my every sub reducer it can did word normally. Something wrong?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The `initialState` argument in `createStore()` is often tripping people. It was never meant as a way to “initialize” your application state manually. The only useful applications for it are:

- Booting up server rendered app from JSON state payload.
- “Resuming” the app from a state saved into local storage.

It is implied that you never write `initialState` manually and in most apps you don’t even use it. Instead, reducers must always specify their own initial state, and `initialState` is just a way to prefill that state when you have an existing serialized version of it.

So [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36620420/458193) is correct: you **need** to define the initial state in your reducer. Supplying it to `createStore()` is not enough, and is not meant to be a way to define the initial state in code.

Comment: This seems to contradict the description in Redux documentation: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/InitializingState.html

Comment: From redux docs `All reducers are passed undefined on initialization, so they should be written such that when given undefined`

Comment: @aks answer is actually more appropriate. I have had a similar issue but probably caused by the same problem. I discovered, that reducers are supposed to handle `undefined` states as parameter and are suppose to return the initial state in those cases, as per redux documentation.

Comment: @martin I struggle to understand why would Redux ever pass `undefined` as the value for a reducer if it gets the initial value.

Answer (score 109):

**I had the same error but I didn't include a default case**

```
function generate(state={} ,action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case randomNumber:
      return {
        ...state,
        random: action.payload
      }   
    default: // need this for default case
      return state 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 46):

Also, make sure that you are returning the **default state** last in your reducer.  Sometimes you can forget to make sure this is the default for your switch statement (when refactoring and moving around code).

```
...
 default:
  return state
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This was an absolute life saver. Can't say it enough.

Comment: No problem!  I have even landed on this same answer for the same issue when using my own copy pasta that is redux actions ;)

Answer (score 33):

When your reducers are called for the first time, state is undefined. You must then return the initial state (that's what the error message is telling you). 
The usual way of defining the initial state value is to set a default value for the state parameter:

```
function postsBySubreddit(state = {}, action) {}
```

You have an initial state in the `posts` function but it is not called during initialization.

Comment: but I have a initial state in createStore method on second arguments

Comment: You're right. It looks like one of the keys doesn't match the reducer: selectedsubreddit => selectedSubreddit. Could it be the source of error?

Comment: In the morning it runs correctly, but in this afternoon it can't work and browser show same error . I never change my code but it stills show same  error

Answer (score 9):

I just hit this same snag because I accidentally redefined `state` inside my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  previous: true,
  later: true
}

const useTypeReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_USE_TYPES':
      let state = Object.assign({}, state);   // DON'T REDEFINE STATE LIKE THIS!
      state[action.use] = !state[action.use];
      return state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default useTypeReducer;
```

To fix the problem I needed to refrain from redefining state:

```
const initialState = {
  previous: true,
  later: true
}

const useTypeReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_USE_TYPES':
      let _state = Object.assign({}, state);   // BETTER
      _state[action.use] = !state[action.use];
      return _state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default useTypeReducer;
```

Answer (score 6):

as per the documentation of redux: https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers

you need to return state out side of switch function
like this:

```
 function posts(state=initialState,action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
      return state.merge({
        didInvalidate: true
      })
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
      return state.merge({
        isFetching: true,
        didInvalidate: false
      })
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
      return state.merge({
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        items: action.posts,
        lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
      })
    default:
      return state 
    }

//here you should put the return state
return state
}
```

Comment: if we return state outside switch statement it becomes unreachable

Comment: hmm I was following the documentation. It probably updated now. Thank you for noticing

Comment: @KhorramBinSalimKhondkar it doesn't make any sense anyways. Switch case just represents conditions and default condition is what to do as default.

Comment: @irfanwani please refer to documentation of redux for more clarity: 
https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers
Thank you

Comment: @khorram Bin Salim Khondkar, same in docs too. Return the state in default case as that is what it would be like returning state from a function if we don't have switch case

Answer (score 5):

For me, I had my reducer like

```
import * as actions from '../actions/budgetActions';

export const initialState = {
    budget: {},
    loading: false,
    hasErrors: false,
}

export default function budgetReducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.GET_BUDGET:
            return { ...state, loading: true };
        case actions.GET_BUDGET_SUCCESS:
            return { budget: action.payload, loading: false, hasErrors: false };
        case actions.GET_BUDGET_FAILURE:
            return { ...state, loading: false, hasErrors: true };
    }
}
```

instead of (I was missing a default case)

```
   import * as actions from '../actions/budgetActions';
    
    export const initialState = {
        budget: {},
        loading: false,
        hasErrors: false,
    }
    
    export default function budgetReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    
        switch (action.type) {
            case actions.GET_BUDGET:
                return { ...state, loading: true };
            case actions.GET_BUDGET_SUCCESS:
                return { budget: action.payload, loading: false, hasErrors: false };
            case actions.GET_BUDGET_FAILURE:
                return { ...state, loading: false, hasErrors: true };
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

ensure you have a default state at the end like so

```
...
default:
  return state;
```

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

Make sure that:

- You actually pass data to your reducer via the action/action creator!
- The reducer doesn't return `undefined`.

### Example

```js
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_DATA':
      debugger // Place a breakpoint for investigation
      const result = update(state, {$set: action.data});
      // `result` is `undefined` if `action.data` is too
      return result;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

In this case, if you accidentally pass `undefined` to `action.data` via your action creator then [react-addons-update](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-update) will return the `undefined` that came from that variable. Since this overwrites the whole reducer state it will return that `undefined` that will trigger the error.

### Debugging

You can debug this by examining these places:

- Where the reducer creates the new state. Place a breakpoint into that part to make sure you don't receive or return `undefined` there.
- Where the data is passed to the action creator.

Answer (score 1):

in case of createStore() make sure that the reducer is initialised

**Example**

```
const init = {
  state: true,
  value: 0
}

const value = (prev = init, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'increment':
            return {
                ...prev,
                value: prev.value + 1
            }
        case 'decrement':
            return {
                ...prev,
                value: prev.value - 1
            }
        default:
            return { ...prev }
    }
}
```

in the case of the redux toolkit inside the createSlice() object make sure that the key initialState is used and initialized and named as exactly initialState.

**Example**

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
const valueSlice = createSlice({
 name: 'value',
    initialState: 0,
      reducers: {
        increment: (state, action) => {
            return state + 1;
        },
        decrement: (state, action) => {
            return state - 1;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: wow dude.. thanks for your help, i need this answer.. maybe react-redux without toolkit is outdated but i need this for my study redux basic.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 const firstReducer = (state = 0) => {   
        switch (0) {
     case 0:
       return state + 1;
     default:// add this default in user reducer functions
       return state;   
 } };  export default firstReducer;
```