# Receiving error: Reducer […] returned undefined during initialization

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

So I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619093/why-do-i-get-reducer-returned-undefined-during-initialization-despite-pr) cause it looks similar. But that did not help.

Versions:

```
react@16.0.0-alpha.12
react-native@0.47.2
react-redux@5.0.6
redux@3.7.2
```

Structure:

```
|index.android.js
  |src
     |actions
        |peopleActions
        |peopleConst
     |reducers
        |index
        |reducers-people
     |components
        |configureStore
```

actions/peopleConst.js :

```
export const FETCHING_PEOPLE = 'FETCHING_PEOPLE'
export const FETCHING_PEOPLE_SUCCESS = 'FETCHING_PEOPLE_SUCCESS'
export const FETCHING_PEOPLE_FAILURE = 'FETCHING_PEOPLE_FAILURE'
```

actions/peopleActions.js :

```
import { 
         FETCHING_PEOPLE, 
         FETCHING_PEOPLE_SUCCESS, 
         FETCHING_PEOPLE_FAILURE } from './peopleConst'

export function fetchPeopleFromAPI() {
    return(dispatch) => {
        dispatch(getPeople())
        fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => dispatch(getPeopleSuccess(json.results)))
        .catch(err => dispatch(getPeopleFailure(err)))
    }
}

function getPeople(){
    return {
        type:FETCHING_PEOPLE
    }
}

function getPeopleSuccess(data){
    return {
        type:FETCHING_PEOPLE_SUCCESS,
        data
    }
}

function getPeopleFailure(){
    return {
        type:FETCHING_PEOPLE_FAILURE
    }
}
```

reducers/reducers-people:

```
import { 
        FETCHING_PEOPLE, 
        FETCHING_PEOPLE_SUCCESS, 
        FETCHING_PEOPLE_FAILURE } from '../actions/peopleConst'

const initialState = {
    people: [],
    isFetching: false,
    error: false
}

export default function peopleReducer(
    state = {                 // <= Also tried state={initialState}
            people: [],
            isFetching: false,
            error: false }, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "FETCHING_PEOPLE":
          return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: true, 
            people: []
          }
        case "FETCHING_PEOPLE_SUCCESS":
          return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: false,
            people: action.data
          }
        case "FETCHING_PEOPLE_FAILURE":
          return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: false,
            error: true
          }
        defualt: 
          return state
    }
}
```

reducers/index:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import peopleReducer from './reducers-people';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    people: peopleReducer
});

export default allReducers;
```

components/configureStore:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers'

const myLogger = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  console.log("Logged Action: ", action);
  next(action);
}

const middleware = applyMiddleware(logger, thunk);

export default function configureStore(){
  let store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, middleware)
  return store
}
```

The reducer does not have an empty state and has initialState predefined and used when defining the state like:

```
export default function peopleReducer(
        state = {                 // <= Also tried state={initialState}
                people: [],
                isFetching: false,
                error: false }, action) {
```

But still its failing with this error. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I see a typo: `defualt` instead of `default` in the switch/case construct

Comment: thank you @LucaFabbri. What a silly mistake I made. Everything works like a charm. Btw, would you recommend any package/tutorial to use with API and calls on API please. I want to fetch the data and manipulate it. Like change some state in it in the DB.