# Why redux reducer getting 'undefined' instead of the initial state?

Tags: node.js, redux, react-redux

I create a toy example with NodeJS and redux.
I create a store like this:

```
var initialState = {config: defaultConfig, customData: data};
const store = createStore(reducers, initialState)
```

I make sure `defaultConfig` and `data` are defined, i.e. i really stop the debugger before the statement and I can confirm the config is really there. However, inside the reducers, the state is `undefined`. Why?!

The reducers are:

```
const configReducer = (config: any, action: any): any =>{
        return config;
}

const customData = (customData: any, action: any): any =>  {
        return customData;
}
const reducers = combineReducers({config: configReducer, customData: customDataReducer})
```

So I am explicitly giving an initial state, but redux will call the reducers with `undefined`.

I know I could put the initial state as default parameter in the reducers, or use any other work around. That is not the question here.

The question is: why this is not working if I pass the initial state when building the store.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619093/why-do-i-get-reducer-returned-undefined-during-initialization-despite-pr

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is specific to [`combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers):

> Any reducer passed to combineReducers must satisfy these rules:
>
> - For any action that is not recognized, it must return the state given to it as the first argument.
> - It must never return undefined. It is too easy to do this by mistake via an early return statement, so combineReducers throws if you do
>     that instead of letting the error manifest itself somewhere else.
> - If the state given to it is undefined, it must return the initial state for this specific reducer. According to the previous rule, the
>     initial state must not be undefined either. It is handy to specify it
>     with ES6 optional arguments syntax, but you can also explicitly check
>     the first argument for being undefined.

With `combineReducers`, a reducer is [initially called with `undefined`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/v4.0.1/src/combineReducers.js#L68) to assert that it doesn't break these rules. Only then it will be called with `initialState`.

So `initialState` is intended to hydrate the state with *initial* values, not provide *default* values.

A reducer should be able to handle unexpected state on unexpected action (`default` clause in `switch`), in this case initial value should be forcedto be anything but `undefined`, e.g.:

```
const configReducer = (config: any = null, action: any): any =>{
        return config;
}

const customData = (customData: any = null, action: any): any =>  {
        return customData;
}
```

Comment: Sorry your answer does not make sense. Because:

The problem is that redux is failing when I do what rule 1. says.

So, redux is calling the reducer with argument ```undefined``` so according to rule 1 I should return ```undefined```. Butr rule 2 says I should never return ```undefined```.

Also, this is NOT specific of combineReducers. The same behavior happens when I make my own rootreducer.

Comment: *it must return the state given to it as the first argument* - this includes [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). It does make sense because that's true situation. That's what documentation says. If you feel the documentation contradicts itself, consider opening an issue in Redux repo (actually, they confuse argument and parameter). It [doesn't work with combineReducers](https://codesandbox.io/s/qz176kj63q). It [does work without it](https://codesandbox.io/s/q3plokv43w).

Comment: Your question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so I can't say why it doesn't work in your case. Please, provide MCVE.

Comment: there is already an issue open about it: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/2578

Comment: I really do not get your answer.

Comment: This is the issue about related problem, not about a problem with documentation. `combineReducers` will call reducers with `undefined` state the first time, regardless of `initialState`. You can avoid this by specifying default param value. It can be `config: any = defaultConfig` or whatever. If this doesn't work for you, please provide MCVE. It's required by SO rules, exactly to avoid situations where correct answer may not work for you.

Comment: "With combineReducers, a reducer is initially called with undefined to assert that it doesn't break these rules. Only then it will be called with initialState.". That statement needs to be in the redux doc.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I used redux-persist and it returned old state of slice.

So just clear storage you use:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Giving initial state while creating store will not initialise your store. You have to explicitly set initial state in reducers.

Please refer [Why do I get “Reducer [...] returned undefined during initialization” despite providing initialState to createStore()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619093/why-do-i-get-reducer-returned-undefined-during-initialization-despite-pr)

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue and while I debugged the code it will be your object with key because each state maintained separate object.

```
const reducers = combineReducers({config: configReducer, customData: customDataReducer})
```

Here when you get data with undefined by default your state is like

```
{config:undefined, customData:undefinded}
```

Why??: Because combineReducer function has an option to provide initial state to each key or say separate states like below otherwise optional to pass initial state with undefined by default

```
    const initialRootState={config:{}, customData:{}};
    const reducers = combineReducers({config: configReducer, 
                     customData: customDataReducer});

    const store= createStore(reducers,initialRootState);
```

Now when your reducer initialized state with default case

```
 export default function configReducer(state = initialState, action){}
    //state = initialState even undefined called
 export default function customDataReducer(state = initialState, action){}
    //state = initialState even undefined called
```

But it will return undefined due to normal behavior of combineReducers function to pass your initial state with default "undefined"  {config:undefined, customData:undefinded} and your state object will look like
`state:{config:{initialState}}` for configReducer
`state:{customData:{initialState}}` for customDataReducer

Answer (score 0):

if you're getting undefined, then replace it... in my case, when my server reply without the data for any reason, maybe because there is not active session, I got that problem, so doing this in the reducer, worked as a charm for me:

```
export default function itemReducer(state = initialState.items | undefined, action){ 
    switch(action.type) 
   { 
         case "LOAD_ITEMS_SUCCESS":
               if(action.items==undefined) { 
                        action.items=[]; 
               }
                return action.items
```

If the reducer gets undefined, then replace undefined for an empty array, and you won't get that error anymore.

Cheers!